# "If this is the max value in a range..."

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have an array of numbers, all calculated, is there any reasonable way to have in all the cells "if this is the maximum value of the range, add 10 to it"?

To put it another way, for clarity, I want the highest value in a range (or values, I guess, in case of a tie) to take a value 10 higher than they otherwise would.

Comment: Try `=<current formula>+(<current formula>=MAX(<range>))*10`

Comment: 10 added when? once? each time a value is updated? how does the system know when the range is fully populated? you could have a cell that contains the max value in a range and adds 10 to it... what should happen in case of ties?

Comment: ...thanks, Jeeped. I think that'll work. Can't believe I didn't think of that myself. Though it does give a circular reference warning.

Comment: Damn. Sadly, the circular reference stops it from working properly - it won't calculate.

Comment: Well you _can_ allow circular reference if you go to Excel Options | Formulas | Enable Iterative Calculations but is there any reason not to put @Jeeped's suggestion in another column so that you remove the circular reference?

Comment: Mostly lack of space in the sheet. I can probably stick a new row in there without breaking anything though.